# Direct the user to the homepage once google sign in is clicked

Tags: java, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase utils where I have declared the sign in with google. However, once signed in, it does direct the user to the homepage.

```
const GoogleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
GoogleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider);
```

In logging in using google, I've used a button onClick:

```
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../../Firebase/utils";
 <ButtonForm onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
            Continue with Gmail
          </ButtonForm>
```

Comment: Ohh sorry, I might have forgotten  about it. Thank you, I've checkmark the answer and upvoted the others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`signInWithPopup` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithpopup) returns a promise that resolves once the user is signed in. So you can wait for that promise to resolve, and then redirect.

```
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider).then((userCredential) => {
    // redirect here
  }
}
```

---

This will work when the use actively signs in, but not when the user revisits the page. If you also want to redirect in those cases, consider [using an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) instead, and redirect in there once the `user` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `signInWithRedirect` function from firebase.

See full API here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithredirect